# Solving Knight's Travails Problem without using vector for position

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, functional-programming, clojure, chess

I'm trying to implement a solution to the [The Odin Project - Project 2: Knight’s Travails](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/data-structures-and-algorithms) in Clojure (Functional Programming) based on the solution posted by [benjdelt](https://github.com/benjdelt/knights_travails/blob/master/main.rb).

I would like to know your opinion about what should I change to make the code clearer and more functional (as in Functional Programming) and how should I document it.

I don't know if this code is considered functional. I am relying heavily on recursions, is this ok? If not, how can I `reduce` (or use any other method) to make it more functional?

**Note**: Instead of using a vector with position x and y "[x, y]", I chose to represent the chess board by the square index, e.g. the first square is at index 0, the second square is at index 1 ... the last square is at index 63.

```clj
(def board
 "- Not used anywhere yet, just shows how the board looks like. -"
  [(vec (range 0 8))
   (vec (range 8 16))
   (vec (range 16 24))
   (vec (range 24 32))
   (vec (range 32 40))
   (vec (range 40 48))
   (vec (range 48 56))
   (vec (range 56 64))])

(defn knight-moves
  "Get all the allowed moves of a knight at `node` position.
  Excludes all the moves that go out of the board."
  ([node]
  (let [a (- node 17)
        b (- node 15)
        c (- node 10)
        d (- node 6)
        e (+ node 6)
        f (+ node 10)
        g (+ node 15)
        h (+ node 17)
        all-neighbours [a b c d e f g h]
        possible-neighbours (vec (remove #(or (neg? %) (> % 63)) all-neighbours))]
    {:neighbours possible-neighbours :current-node node :parent-node nil}))
  ([node parent]
   (let [a (- node 17)
         b (- node 15)
         c (- node 10)
         d (- node 6)
         e (+ node 6)
         f (+ node 10)
         g (+ node 15)
         h (+ node 17)
         all-neighbours [a b c d e f g h]
         possible-neighbours (vec (remove #(or (neg? %) (> % 63)) all-neighbours))]
     {:neighbours possible-neighbours :current-node node :parent-node parent})))

;; (knight-moves 35)

(defn nodes
  "Get all the neighbours and subsequent neighbours of `starting-node`.
  Given a `node`, return a vector of maps with all the possible neighbours and
  subsequent neighbours.
  Given a `node` and a `parent`, return a vector of maps with all the possible
  nodes and subsequent neighbours and save its parent location."
  ([starting-node]
  (let [movements (knight-moves starting-node)]
    ;; For each neighbours of `starting-node`, calculate its subsequent neighbours.
    (vec (for [node (:neighbours movements)]
           (knight-moves node (knight-moves starting-node))))))
  ([starting-node parent]
   (let [movements (knight-moves starting-node)]
     (vec (for [node (:neighbours movements)]
            (knight-moves node (knight-moves starting-node parent)))))))

;; (nodes 35)

(defn backtracking
  "Return the parent location of each subsequent node in `path`."
  ([final-node] (backtracking final-node []))
  ([final-node path]
   (if (:parent-node final-node)
     (recur (:parent-node final-node) (merge path (:current-node final-node)))
     (reverse (distinct path)))))

(defn find-path
  "Given a `starting-node`, calculate the path to the `goal-node`"
  ([starting-node goal-node]
   (find-path (knight-moves starting-node) goal-node []))
  ([starting-node goal-node path]
   ;; If not yet arrived at goal
   (if-not (= (:current-node starting-node) goal-node)
     ;; Create a new node with the current-node as parent and add it to path.
     ;; Iterate through all nodes to find the path.
     (let [new-node (nodes (:current-node starting-node) starting-node)
           path (concat path new-node)]
       (recur (first path) goal-node (vec (concat (rest path) new-node))))
     ;; If path found, return the path
     (backtracking starting-node))))

;; (find-path 27 28)

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (find-path 27 28))

(-main)
; => (27 12 18 28)
```

Comment: I'm glad you found my review helpful, but, I wouldn't accept so quickly if I were you. You don't want to discourage any other answers. I also may be able to add to my answer later. I have a hell of a day in front of me and wanted to get the main things I saw addressed. I may be able to find more things when I have time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be commenting just on the code itself, not on improvements to the algorithm. I'll also be removing your docs for brevity here.

First, I see a *ton* of repetitious code here. `board` and `knight-moves` contain a lot of duplicate code that can be generalized and cleaned up.

---

First, `board`:

```
(defn board [side-length]
  (->> (range (* side-length side-length)) ; Create all the numbered cells
       (partition side-length) ; Split them into rows
       (mapv vec))) ; Turn the board into a 2D vector
```

I turned it into a function that accepts the side length, and made it so it can handle whatever valid values you throw at it.

---

The different arity versions of `knight-moves` are almost identical. The only difference is that `parent` defaults to `nil`. This can be easily reduced:

```
(defn knight-moves
  ([node]
   (knight-moves node nil)) ; Default parent to nil

  ([node parent]
   (let [a (- node 17)
         b (- node 15)
         c (- node 10)
         d (- node 6)
         e (+ node 6)
         f (+ node 10)
         g (+ node 15)
         h (+ node 17)
         all-neighbours [a b c d e f g h]
         possible-neighbours (vec (remove #(or (neg? %) (> % 63)) all-neighbours))]
     {:neighbours possible-neighbours :current-node node :parent-node parent})))
```

That's still super bulky though. I bet there's a way to handle this without hardcoding all the numbers, but I can't think of it right now. A significantly more succinct version however could be:

```
(defn knight-moves
  ([node]
   (knight-moves node nil)) ; Default parent to nil

  ([node parent]
   (let [offsets [6 10 15 17]
         pos (map #(+ node %) offsets) ; Just map over the offsets so you aren't writing them twice.
         neg (map #(- node %) offsets)

         ; I'm reversing neg here so it matches your previous output. It seems valid without,
         ;  it just gives different answers.
         all-neighbours (vec (concat (reverse neg) pos)) ; Then stick the two together.
         possible-neighbours (vec (remove #(or (neg? %) (> % 63)) all-neighbours))]
     {:neighbours possible-neighbours :current-node node :parent-node parent})))
```

Note how I'm reversing `neg`. If I don't, the `-main` will return different results. The results without the call to `reverse` should be valid, they're just different from what you were getting before.

---

In `nodes`, I think you're trying too hard to use both arities of `knight-moves`, which is leading to duplicate code. Why not just pass `nil`? I'd also use `mapv` here instead of `for`. `for` is really only beneficial when you need to make use of it's ability to generate combinations, or make use of `:when`/`:while`:

```
(defn nodes
  ([starting-node]
   (nodes starting-node nil)) ; Default to nil, just like before

  ([starting-node parent]
   (let [movements (knight-moves starting-node)]
     ; You could use a full fn here instead of relying on the function macro
     ;  if you want a better identifier than %
     (mapv #(knight-moves % (knight-moves starting-node parent))
           (:neighbours movements)))))
```

---

I honestly couldn't find anything glaringly wrong with the rest of the code, so I left it as-is. This is the final result that I ended up with:

```
(ns irrelevant.knights.corrected)

(defn board
  [side-length]
  (->> (range (* side-length side-length)) ; Create all the numbered cells
       (partition side-length) ; Split them into rows
       (mapv vec))) ; Turn the board into a 2D vector

(defn knight-moves
  ([node]
   (knight-moves node nil)) ; Default parent to nil

  ([node parent]
   (let [offsets [6 10 15 17]
         pos (map #(+ node %) offsets) ; Just map over the offsets so you aren't writing them twice.
         neg (map #(- node %) offsets)

         ; I'm reversing neg here so it matches your previous output. It seems valid without,
         ;  it just gives different answers.
         all-neighbours (vec (concat (reverse neg) pos)) ; Then stick the two together.
         possible-neighbours (vec (remove #(or (neg? %) (> % 63)) all-neighbours))]
     {:neighbours possible-neighbours :current-node node :parent-node parent})))

(defn nodes
  ([starting-node]
   (nodes starting-node nil)) ; Default to nil, just like before

  ([starting-node parent]
   (let [movements (knight-moves starting-node)]
     ; You could use a full fn here instead of relying on the function macro
     ;  if you want a better identifier than %
     (mapv #(knight-moves % (knight-moves starting-node parent))
           (:neighbours movements)))))

(defn backtracking
  ([final-node] (backtracking final-node []))
  ([final-node path]
   (if (:parent-node final-node)
     (recur (:parent-node final-node) (merge path (:current-node final-node)))
     (reverse (distinct path)))))

(defn find-path
  ([starting-node goal-node]
   (find-path (knight-moves starting-node) goal-node []))
  ([starting-node goal-node path]
    ;; If not yet arrived at goal
   (if-not (= (:current-node starting-node) goal-node)
     ;; Create a new node with the current-node as parent and add it to path.
     ;; Iterate through all nodes to find the path.
     (let [new-node (nodes (:current-node starting-node) starting-node)
           path (concat path new-node)]
       (recur (first path) goal-node (vec (concat (rest path) new-node))))
     ;; If path found, return the path
     (backtracking starting-node))))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (find-path 27 28))

(-main)
; => (27 12 18 28)
```

Comment: I find your code much cleaner and understadable than the one I wrote. I'm new to Functional Programming so I don't understand yet how to simplify this things. I spent a few days trying to figure how to do it in Clojure, and now, with your help, I think that maybe its even simpler than OOP Paradigm. I created a repository on [`GitHub`](https://github.com/vascoferreira25/knights_travails) with this project and I hope you don't mind that I referenced this post and your name as a helper.

Comment: @VascoFerreira If you haven't tried it already, I recommend trying to write an implementation for Conway's Game of Life. It's my favorite simple project to do when starting a new language. It's not very difficult to create, but it contains many different aspects to it, so it forces you to learn a little of everything. I'd also recommend a good book like Clojure for the Brave and True. You might also want to look over other [Clojure reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clojure) to see what other people are doing. And ya, its fine to reference me in that project.